# DRF Get All Fields of OneToOne Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm relatively new to DRF and currently stuck at an issue. After lot of trials I tried looking around but couldn't find something what I want. In case this question has already been answered please do direct me to the original question. Thanks in advance for the help!

Problem:
I've a profile model that has one to one relation with User model. When I create a new user object the profile object is auto created as expected. I would like to create an API such that when I execute it like `api/profile/` in addition to returning the profile model fields it should also return all the fields from User model i.e. `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email` etc...

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    rater = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='approval')
    certified = models.ManyToManyField(Protocol, blank=True, default=None, related_name='trained')
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My ProfileSerializer is as follows:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    approval = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I run the API I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rater": 3,
        "certified": [],
        "is_approved": false
    }
]
```

How can I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rater": 3,
        "certified": [],
        "is_approved": false,
        "first_name": xyz,
        "last_name": abc,
        "username": 123,
        "email": abc@gmail.com,
    }
]
```

Comment: Don't you want the user details nested? Or does it have to be flat?

Comment: Doesn't matter either will work.. I just added that as an example for the users to understand what kind of data I'm expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a few ways. The best way would be to make a serializer that contains fields from both models. What you have is close, but because your related field name is `rater` on the Profile side of the relationship. (e.g. you use `profile.rater.email`, not `profile.approval`)

You should either use the name `rater` or specify `source` keyword argument.

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    approval = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='rater')
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you want the result to be flat, rather than nested, you can specify a `to_representation` method.

```py
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # get the usual response as a dictionary
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        # pop the nested field and flatten
        user_details = representation.pop('approval')
        representation.update(user_details)
        return representation
```

You could also 'cheat' and do this straight from the `to_representation` method altogether, although it requires a bit more verbosity and you don't get the advantage of all the definitions from the UserSerializer. But this may be useful if you don't have a serializer and don't want to make one for some reason.

```py
   def to_representation(self, instance):
       representation = super().to_representation(instance)
       user = instance.rater
       representation.update({'email': user.email,
                              'first_name', user.first_name,
                              ...
                              })
       return representation
```

Comment: Excellent explanation!!! Thanks a lot for making it super precise, clear. I wish the documentation of django was as clear as this.. Amazing and thanks again :)

Comment: is there a way to make only a specific field from the user model editable? Now since I've defined `read_only=True` all the user model fields are non-editable but I would like to make `first_name` and `last_name` editable. Can I override them in the ProfileSerializer?

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify `read_only=True` you can edit fields on the related field according to the field definitions in the `UserSerializer`. If necessary, you could make another serializer (say, a subclass of your `UserSerializer`) that changes the fields if necessarily different from other views that may use `UserSerializer`.  There's maybe a few other ways to accomplish this. DRF is a pretty flexible framework. @Alex

Comment: Yes I understand if I remove `read_only=True` or if I have another serializer for changing fields it would work, but I was thinking if there is an efficient way of overriding only a specific field without using the above two ways.. Can sulgrelated field be used for this task or may be update method @sytech ?

Comment: Using a new serializer is probably the way to go. I'm not sure there's many other methods that allow you to control the precise fields. The part of the docs you want to look over for this is [dealing with nested objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects). Maybe you can use `depth` and maybe fields allows you to specify related fields, too?  (I'm not sure) maybe `depth=2` and `fields=[<all profile fields>, 'rater__first_name', rater__last_name', ...]` ? But I don't see anything in the docs like that. But this is already more verbose :/

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `approval` to `rater`:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rater = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

This will automatically pick up the `rater` field from `Profile` and pass it on to `UserSerializer`.

This way you will end up with:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "certified": [],
        "is_approved": false,
        "rater": {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "xyz",
            "last_name": "abc",
            "username": "123",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes it works!!! Thanks a lot. Just for curiosity is it possible to have same level flat representation and if it isn't too much trouble could you help me understand why using the related_name didn't work?

Comment: The related name `approval` is for the other side of the relation which is `User`. So it will be used for something like: `user.approval` which pertains to the profile. Actually to make more sense, `approval` should be `profile`. So you can access profile from user by: `user.profile`

Comment: Yes flat is possible. As a hint, you can override the serializer's `to_representation`, or use [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) in the fields

Comment: The hint for both `source` and `to_representation` is answered by @sytech :D

Comment: Ohh using the source... I have been already doing that and I was just wondering if there is  some easier and more efficient way for it!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you rather need to get things dynamically...

related fields on a model:

```py
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
relational_fields = [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.fields if isinstance(f, ForeignKey)]
```

`OneToOne` fields on a model:

```py
from django.db.models import OneToOneField
one2one_fields = [f.name for f in MyModel._meta.fields if isinstance(OneToOneField)]
```

reverse related fields on a model:

```py
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
rev_related_field_names = [
    attr
    for attr in dir(model_cls)
    if isinstance(getattr(model_cls, attr).field, ForeignKey)
]
```

reverse `OneToOneField`s:

```py
from django.db.models import OneToOneField
rev_one2one_field_names = [
    attr
    for attr in dir(model_cls)
    if isinstance(getattr(model_cls, attr).field, OneToOneField)
]
```